# CKeditor component with angular2 angular cli

Tags: angular, ckeditor, angular-cli

I am trying run ckeditor with Angular2. I'm using the Angular CLI, and I have a very basic working app.

I have intstalled [this package](https://github.com/chymz/ng2-ckeditor) using `npm install ng2-ckeditor`. I have set my `system.config.js` file exactly as per their example, ie:

```
System.config({
    "map": {
      "ng2-ckeditor": "npm:ng2-ckeditor",
    },
    "packages": {
      "ng2-ckeditor": {
        "main": "lib/index.js",
        "defaultExtension": "js",
      },
    }
  });
```

and included it in my `app.modules.ts` in the same way:

import { CKEditorModule } from 'ng2-ckeditor';

```
@NgModule({
  // ...
  imports:      [
    CKEditorModule
  ],
  // ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

After running `ng build` and `ng serve` I get the following error in my console:

> Unexpected value 'CKEditorModule' imported by the module 'AppModule'

I don't understand why?

Comment: This answer is fully answered for Angular 4 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44598775/6266192).

Answer (score 6):

I found a way to this problem:

1. In your index.html just add this in the header block:

`<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.1/full/ckeditor.js"></script>`

2. Install ng2-ckeditor via NPM

   `npm install ng2-ckeditor --save`
3. In your app.component.ts add this:

   `import { CKEditorComponent } from '../../../node_modules/ng2-ckeditor/src/ckeditor.component';
   @NgModule({
       declarations: [
           CKEditorComponent
       ],
       exports: [
           CKEditorComponent,
              ]
   })`
4. Use editor like this:

   `<ckeditor [(ngModel)]="myContent" debounce="500"></ckeditor>`

Comment: +1 for the example. Is there a way to add external plugins which requires modification of config.js? The plugin in question is [pbckcode]
(https://github.com/prbaron/pbckcode).