# CKEditor : wordcount - unable to find in CDN

Tags: ckeditor4.x, ckeditor-wordcount

how to use wordcount or any other plugin when referrring to CDN script.

**Question-1:**
I'm referring to below CDN and I have added extraplugin in config.js. But it says unable to find "wordcount". it is full-all package not sure why it is unable to find.
src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.8.0/full-all/ckeditor.js"

**Question-2:**
is there a way to download full-all(full package doesn't have all plugins enabled) from builder. instead have everything locally.

**Question-3:**
without CDN URL ng2-ckeditor doesn't display the content in editor. I wan it to work with local package.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using the ng2-ckeditor component for angular.

Answer 1: You can add extraplugins as [follow](https://github.com/chymz/ng2-ckeditor/issues/159).

Answer 2: Yes you can download the full package from [here](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/download/)

Answer 3: Please look at the following description on ng2-ckeditor github [page](https://github.com/chymz/ng2-ckeditor/issues/9) and [here](https://github.com/chymz/ng2-ckeditor/issues/136).