# Add CKEditor in angular 5 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, ckeditor

I am pretty new to angular. I want to add CKEditor in my angular 5 App with RoR. I have no idea about how to configure and use CKEditor. Can someone tell me how to use it in my app?

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to integrate CKEditor in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41816263/how-to-integrate-ckeditor-in-angular-2)

Comment: Please check out my projekt at https://github.com/dirbacke/ckeditor4, it might help you get started, but it's not RoR.