# Cannot find name 'CKEDITOR'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.CKEDITOR'?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ckeditor

I am developing a PWA with Ionic 3. I have used CKEDITOR to get rich input from users.
I am importing CKEDITOR library in the *index.html* with the code:

```
  <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.1/full/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

I am also importing CKEditorModule in the app.module.ts as mentioned in the documentation.

Then I am supposed to be able to use CKEDITOR class in my application. The problem is that on first load it shows the error:

> Cannot find name 'CKEDITOR'. Did you mean the instance member
>   'this.CKEDITOR'?

Then if I save my editor and it live reloads then CKEDITOR is working properly.

I have tried to work with life cycle events like **ngAfterViewInit()** in order to only use CKEDITOR variable once it is supposed to be completely loaded, in vain.

I also used **ionViewDidEnter** lifecycle like:

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
    CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (this) {
      console.log(this);
      //Disable automatic inline for divs with contenteditable true.
      this.disableAutoInline = true;

      this.instances["titre"].on('focus', function (this) { this.execCommand('selectAll', false, null); });
      this.instances["adress"].on('focus', function (this) { this.execCommand('selectAll', false, null); });
      this.instances["budget"].on('focus',function (this) { this.execCommand('selectAll', false, null); });
      this.instances["name"].on('focus',   function (this) { this.execCommand('selectAll', false, null); });
      this.instances["description"].on('focus', function (this) { this.execCommand('selectAll', false, null); });

    });
```

CKEDITOR is still not recognized on a first load? Any tip on how I could find the issue here ?

Here is a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-j2gftm?file=pages/home/home.ts) for more comprehension: 
(You need to go to the console to see the bug, on stackblitz the page will eventually reload so the editor works, but in my case it is just stuck on the error.

**Edit of the Stablitz : [Stackblitz edit](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-pykhix?file=pages/home/home.html)**

[image: BUG]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41816263/how-to-integrate-ckeditor-in-angular-2

Comment: no matter what I do, I always end up with the error (see screen shot in the edit post ) @Chellappan

Comment: try this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41816263/how-to-integrate-ckeditor-in-angular-2

Comment: if it is not working please edit stackblitz with your ckeditor code

Comment: @Chellappan I have checked all topics on stackoverflow about that, the issue I face is :Cannot find name 'CKEDITOR'. 
As i've written up above, if I save and it live reloads then my app works !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution :

You need to add

```
declare var CKEDITOR: any;
```

before @component in the .ts file and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I have looked into your code you have used [ng2-ckeditor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-ckeditor). As this package you didn't followed the first step

> Installation Include CKEditor javascript files in your application :

```
<script> src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.11/full/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

You need to add the cdn to your `index.html` and you have imported the `CKEditorModule` correctly in you `app.module.ts`.

**Now** you have to use it in your component as

```
 <ckeditor
    [(ngModel)]="ckeditorContent">
  </ckeditor>
```

- It will load ckeditor and will bind date to its ngModel, for more configuration you can check out [ng2-ckeditor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-ckeditor) docs.

Happy Coding!!

Comment: Unfortunately, I had the javascript file included in index, 
I just forked the file before to include the js file.On my real project the script is included. 

I edited the Stackblitz (https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-pykhix?file=pages/home/home.html)